# Cypress e2e test without using wait function

Tags: reactjs, testing, wait, cypress

I'm new in e2e testing with Cypress and I have a question.

I wrote a test and I want not to use Cypress wait() command in it.

```
it('Should modify checkbox state', () => {
        login();
        cy.visit(TabsSettings.SIZE_FORMATS).then(() => {
            cy.xpath('(//div[@data-qa="sizeFormats"]//*[4]//*//*[1]//*//*//*)[1]', { timeout: 10000 }).click().then(() => {
                expect(
                    cy.xpath('(//input[@type="checkbox"])[1]')
                        .then(checkbox => checkbox).should('be.checked')
                );
            });
            cy.get('span').contains('Change').click().then(() => {
                cy.get('li').contains('Disable').click().then({ timeout: 5000 }, () => {
                    cy.wait(500);
                    cy.xpath('(//div[@data-qa="sizeFormats"]//*[4]//*//*[1]//*//*//*)[1]').click().then(() => {
                        expect(
                            cy.xpath('(//input[@type="checkbox"])[1]')
                                .then(checkbox => checkbox[0]).should('be.checked')
                        );
                    });
                    cy.xpath('(//div[@data-qa="sizeFormats"]//*[4]//*//*[1]//*//*//*)[18]').click().then(() => {
                        expect(
                            cy.xpath('(//input[@type="checkbox"])[2]')
                                .then(checkbox => checkbox[3]).should('not.checked')
                        );
                    });
                });
                cy.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Disable Selected")]').click().then(() => {
                    cy.get('li').contains('Enable').click().then(() => {
                        expect(
                            cy.get('input[type=checkbox]')
                                .then(checkbox => checkbox).should('not.checked')
                        );
                    });
                });
                cy.get('input[type=checkbox]').then(el => el[0].click()).then(() => {
                    expect(
                        cy.get('input[type=checkbox]')
                            .then(checkbox => checkbox).should('be.checked')
                    );
                }).then(() => {
                    cy.xpath('//i').then(x => x[1].click());
                    cy.get('input[type=checkbox]').should('not.checked');
                });
                cy.get('div[data-main-select=true]').then(list => list[1].click()).then(() => {
                    cy.xpath('(//li[contains(text(), "50")])[1]').click().then(() => {
                        cy.get('input[type=checkbox]').should(checkboxes => {
                            expect(checkboxes).to.have.length(51);
                        });
                    });
                });
                cy.xpath('(//div[@data-qa="sizeFormats"]//*[4]//*//*[1]//*//*//*)[1]').click().then(() => {
                    cy.wait(150);
                    expect(
                        cy.get('input[type=checkbox]')
                            .then(checkbox => checkbox).should('be.checked')
                    );
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

My problem is that if I not use that cy.wait(500) command, the test fails.
I googled a lot but I cannot find an answer for my problem.
The project is an React project, using Hooks. What may be caused the problem is that my component renders multiple times after that click() event. The page does not reload, but the main component rerenders several times. If this is the problem, how can I wait for finishing all renderings, and just after that continue the test, without using the wait function ?

Comment: This looks complicated. Let me digest all the code and I will get back to you.

Comment: To get rid of a `cy.wait()` you generally need to make sure the command chain is using Cypress' automatic retry. The `.then(() =>` preceding the wait is breaking that , so ***maybe*** you can solve it by substituting `.should(() =>` - if I understand correctly, should will retry the code within.

Comment: Also, xpath syntax is quite noisy, I would try to replace `cy.xpath()` with `cy.get()` where possible. See the caveats on the [source page](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath#beware-the-xpath--trap)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at it a bit further, you seem to be using a promise-style syntax unnecessarily.

Because Cypress has automatic retry on (most) commands, you can just call the commands sequentially without awaiting the result with `.then(...` constructs.

As an example, your code might be revised to something like this,

```js
it('Should modify checkbox state', () => {
  login();
  cy.visit(TabsSettings.SIZE_FORMATS);
  cy.xpath('(//div[@data-qa="sizeFormats"]//*[4]//*//*[1]//*//*//*)[1]', {timeout: 10000 }).click();

  // cy.xpath('(//input[@type="checkbox"])[1]').then(checkbox => checkbox).should('be.checked')
  cy.get('input[@type="checkbox"]).eq(0).should('be.checked');  // NB eq() has zero-based indexing.

  cy.get('span').contains('Change').click();
  cy.get('li').contains('Disable').click();
  // OR if you have to wait for the Disable button/link to appear, use this
  cy.contains('li', 'Disable').click();

  cy.xpath('(//div[@data-qa="sizeFormats"]//*[4]//*//*[1]//*//*//*)[1]').click();
  cy.get('input[@type="checkbox"]).eq(0).should('be.checked');
  ...
```

I'm not familiar with xpath syntax, so the translation is a guess, but it seems Cypress' commands are a little more readable, have a flatter layout, PLUS you get auto-retry built in, which removes the need to wait for specific periods.

If you want to add to your question a pseudocode translation of the xpath expressions, I'll give you the equivalent Cypress commands.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I was going to say something similar but I'd already bungled my answer so badly that I thought it best not to. Cheers!

Comment: @Erebus, LOL, just shows code like that is hard to understand. I still don't know if it's possible to refactor to simple commands.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think my problem is that I use a loader in my code. When I run the test in Cypress browser I found that on click event when i looked at DOM Snapshot I observed that at after Snapshot I had my loader running, which is cover the container div, so when in test I wrote for ex.: cy.contains something and after that I used click() and in the next line I used cy.get something, that something was covered by loader's div. So, in that case I still don't know how to fix it to not use wait.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but `cy.get('subject)` does not fail because something is covering the subject. If subject is in the DOM, `cy.get()` will find it.

Comment: Also, your `cy.wait()` is 500 ms, but auto-retry will keep retrying for much longer than that, between 4 and 5 seconds. I assume you have a async call after the click (because there is a loader), so the command following click should test for loaded content that was not there before the click, perhaps the size formats - I can't tell unless you explain better the sequence of events and what the xpath queries are doing.

Comment: @RichardMatsen re: `cy.get('subject')` not failing because something is covering it, are you sure? If you are chaining it to `click()` for example, it will fail if it's not visible. The idea is that Cypress is acting like a human would, and if they can't click it, it will fail: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Actionability

Comment: In that scenario, `click()` is failing not `get()`, however you can force the click.

Comment: In the scenario shown in your question, you do not need to `wait()` if you use `get()` correctly, as outlined previously.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to use `wait` with time, but sometimes you may need to wait for a certain request to finish. I find it's the case with some AJAX requests. You can get it to wait for a specific request to finish using route definitions:

```
cy.server()
cy.route('activities/*', 'fixture:activities').as('getActivities')
cy.route('messages/*', 'fixture:messages').as('getMessages')

// visit the dashboard, which should make requests that match
// the two routes above
cy.visit('http://localhost:8888/dashboard')

// pass an array of Route Aliases that forces Cypress to wait
// until it sees a response for each request that matches
// each of these aliases
cy.wait(['@getActivities', '@getMessages'])

// these commands will not run until the wait command resolves above
cy.get('h1').should('contain', 'Dashboard')
```

Read more here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Waiting

Comment: My problem is not on visiting an page, but on waiting on click action to finishing.

Comment: @LevaiFerenc-Tibor I see, yes with React there obviously wouldn't be any network requests to "wait" for. My answer is not relevant then, sorry.